# jQuery plugin dev: null or empty function as default for optional callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm developing my first jQuery plugin that offers a number of optional callbacks. For example, there's an `onChange` callback that fires when the value of an input field changes.

For all of the settings, I have a `defaults` object that holds the default values, which is then merged with the instance settings: `var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);`

What is the best default value for these optional callbacks? Right now, I use `null`, but this requires that I check if the callback is a function or not all over the place:

```
if ($.isFunction(settings.onChange)) {
  settings.onChange(...);
}
```

Is a better default an empty function? Or something else? What's the standard in jQuery plugin development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `null` as the default value and do:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
settings.onChange && settings.onChange(/* arguments */);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best decision - use empty functions